# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.Geometry is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras

I'm using the freely available code `tensorspace.min.js` which can be found over here: https://github.com/tensorspace-team/tensorspace/blob/master/dist/tensorspace.min.js

The error message I'm getting is:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.Geometry is not a constructor`

How can I fix this kind of error?

Here is a short code snippet regarding the error message:

```
createGroupGeometry:function(A,t){let i=new e.Geometry({transparent:!0,opacity:this.minOpacity});return i.colors=t,i.vertices=A,i.colorsNeedUpdate=!0,i.verticesNeedUpdate=!0,i}},yt.prototype=Object.assign(Object.create(hA.prototype),{addLineGroup:function(){this.lineGroupHandler=new St(this,this.context,this.neuralGroup,this.color,this.minOpacity)},init:function(A,t){},assemble:function(A,t){},updateValue:function(A){},clear:function(){},handleClick:function(A){},handleHoverIn:function(A){},handleHoverOut:function(){},loadModelConfig:function(A){},calcCloseButtonSize:function(){return 1},calcCloseButtonPos:function(){return{x:0,y:0,z:0}},getRelativeElements:function(A){return{straight:[],curve:[]}},
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check `<three.Min.js>`, I replaced the file with version 102 to solve this problem

[image]